# Selection of the day of the week for notification in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

The notification works if you set the year, month, day and time. What is required is to configure the notification so that it would come only on Thursdays at 15:00

```
const pushNoti1 = () => {
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  channelId: "test-channel",
  title: "Неблагоприятный день для:",
  message: "Today is Thursday",
  date: new Date("2021-09-29T13:00:00"),
  id: 1
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In Android,You could set it to repeating notifications in react-native-push-notification like this (for every 100 days):
actually You could specify `repeatType` and optionally `repeatTime` (Android-only) while scheduling the local notification. Property `repeatType` could be one of `month, week, day, hour, minute, time`.

`

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
                ...
                date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000 * 60, 
                repeatType:'time',
                repeatTime:(100) * 86400000), //Repeat every 100 days 
                importance:Importance.HIGH
               ...
            });
```

`

Comment: This is not suitable for ios, only for android. ios does not support "repeatTime"
iOS
Property repeatType can only be month, week, day, hour, minute.

NOTE: repeatTime do not work with iOS.